# How to pass stored procedure's parameter values to temp table using MS SQL 2005?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005, parameters

I need to store the procedures acutal parameter values to a temp table. 
I tried to create a script which can be applied for different stored procedures, therefore the script cannot contain the name of the parameters.
For formatting reasons I couldn't add the scipt. Let me explain in words.

I have a temp table with columns ParameterName and ParameterValue
I inserted the Parameternames using table `sys.parameters` 
Within the SP I try to update temp table ParameterValue with parameter values which the SP was called.
I created dynamic SQL for each parameter one-by-one, I used @ParameterName variable to hold the parameter in row
However I cannot add the value of the parameter (the name of given parameter in @ParameterName) to dynamic SQL

Also tried SP_EXECUTESQL

Please help how to solve this one.

Comment: you might be passing incorrect number of params

Comment: Stupid, but how to add code for the question. I always get error massege whatever I do. Are there special chars not allowed for use? Thanks

Comment: Formatting help - http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Checked http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code also, put the code between <pre><code> and </code></pre>, used " but still error.

Comment: Otherwise EXEC('SELECT ' + @ParameterName) gives Must declare the scalar variable "@ClientCode" (@ClientCode is the parameter in row). I cannot make declaration for @ClientCode, since this is a parameter declared for the stored procedures itself.

Comment: You should be able to jest copy and paste it inot the edit window just like everyone else.  If that doesn't work then try pasteing it into Notepad first.  Then copy it from notepad and paste it into the edit window.

Comment: Thanks RBarry. I also tried Notepadd

Answer (score 0):

If you are using dynamic queries,instead of #temp table ,use ##temp table or permanent table. This may solve your issue.

Comment: I used ##. The basic problem is that I cannot get the value of the parameter, since also the name of the parameter is in variable (@ParameterName )

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all of your procedures, their parameters, and their parameter types. If you want it into a temp you can just remove the commented out portion. Also if you want just one procedure, then you can `set @ProcName` to the name of that procedure.

```
declare @ProcName varchar(4000) = null
select 
    o.name as ProcName,
    p.name as ParamName,
    t.name as ParamType
--into #someTemp
from 
    sys.objects o
inner join
    sys.parameters p on p.object_id = o.object_id
inner join
    sys.types t on t.system_type_id = p.system_type_id
where
    o.type = 'P'
    and @ProcName is null or o.name = @ProcName
```

**UPDATE BASED ON YOUR COMMENTS**

```
---------------------------------------------------------
--create a global temp
--Remember SQL will clean up (remove) your temp when it wants
---------------------------------------------------------

create table ##someTemp(
    DT datetime,
    ProcName varchar(256),
    ParamName varchar(128),
    ParamType varchar(128),
    Val varchar(256)) 
go

---------------------------------------------------------
--create the procedure
---------------------------------------------------------

create procedure [dbo].[usp_test_param_insert] (@int char(1), @someString varchar(256))
as

insert into ##someTemp (DT,ProcName,ParamName, ParamType, val) values
(getdate(),'usp_test','@int','int',@int),
(getdate(),'usp_test','@someString','varchar(256)',@someString)


select @int, @someString


GO


---------------------------------------------------------
--call the proc a few times... i put the delay so you
--can see the time stamp changing
---------------------------------------------------------


exec usp_test_param_insert 1,'first string' 
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'
exec usp_test_param_insert 2,'second string' 
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'
exec usp_test_param_insert 3,'third string' 

---------------------------------------------------------
--See your results
---------------------------------------------------------

select * from ##someTemp
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a first step, I got it. However, the goal is to add the current value of the parameter (the values of parameter the stored procedure was called with).

Comment: The name of variable is in <code>@ParameterName</code>